# Can I try the new font Google Sans from Android 8.1 on my phone?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, fonts, 8.1-oreo

Google has introduced *Google Sans* to the upcoming Android 8.1. It looks great and I want to try it on my OnePlus 5 running stock 7.1.1. Is it possible?

Comment: If you can get hold of the font file, check with our [fonts tag-wiki](/tags/fonts/info) :)

Comment: There's a zip file on XDA you can flash if you have a custom recovery

Answer (score 0):

The fonts have now been extracted and repackaged for flashing at [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-max-2/themes/font-android-oreo-8-1-google-sans-t3694864). Basically, just download the zip for "stock ROMs" (verified working for OnePlus devices as stated on the page), flash it with TWRP and you should have it.